# Which of the following firms can operate in a perfectly competitive industry?

Tags: microeconomics

This was a question in a test. I am looking for an explanation for the answer.

Firm A's cost of producing output y > 0 is c(y) = 1 + y

Firm B's cost of producing output y is c(y) = y(1-y)^2

Answer: Firm B can operate in a perfectly competitive industry but A cannot.

Comment: In a perfectly competitive industry, p=MC. If firm A prices at marginal cost, each sold unit contributes zero to profits. Because it also has to pay fixed cost 1, it makes a negative profit in a competitive market.

Comment: @Bayesian i also thought along the same lines. Do you think there is any chance that there might be something more that we're missing out? Maybe I'm just stressed idk.

Comment: No, I am confident that that's it.

Comment: (-1) There is no question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a perfectly competitive industry, we have $p=MC$ in equilibrium.

If firm A prices at marginal cost, each sold unit contributes zero to profits. Because it also has to pay fixed cost 1, it makes a negative profit in a competitive market regardless of how demand looks like. That is, firm A cannot operate in a perfectly competitve industry.

For firm B, you can calculate marginal cost as $\frac{\partial c(y)}{\partial y} =1-4y+3y^2$. Consider the increasing part of this function as the supply curve. Indeed you can find demand functions that intersect this function at a price leading to nonnegative profits. That is, firm B can operate in a perfectly competitve industry.